# Is it possible to replace the favicon href with the inline base64 using webpack?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, build, favicon

I'm generating a unique HTML file (hard requirement) with all my codebase (css, HTML, fonts, inline svgs, etc) using Webpack (v4).

I'm struggling with including the inline favicon image in base64, replacing

`<link rel="icon" href="assets/favicon.png">`

on build time, with

`<link rel="icon" href="data:image/x-icon;base64,UklGRhQBA... <!-- Base64 data -->">`

I've tried several plugins/loaders but none of them seems to work.

Do you know if there is any tool available capable of doing such?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with adding gulpjs to your build chain, this should do it for you https://openbase.com/js/gulp-base64-favicon